# Anomaly Detection using CHIRPS in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

Using the following script, I am trying to do precipitation anomaly detection but I am not able to figure out what is the actual monthly average based on which the anomalies are plotted for the given time period. In other words I want a plot of monthly average for the period of 1981-2019
(code link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/c6aa83b9e57cfb92418cf0cccc1b6148 )

```
//var point = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Point([76.79667658,10.62448299]);

var means = ee.ImageCollection(ee.List.sequence(1, 12)
  .map(function(m) {
    return chirps.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
        .mean()
        .set('month', m);
}));

var start = ee.Date('2015-01-01');
var months = ee.List.sequence(0, 48);
var dates = months.map(function(index) {
  return start.advance(index, 'month');
});
print(dates);

// Group by month, and then reduce within groups by mean();
// the result is an ImageCollection with one image for each
// month.
var byMonth = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
      dates.map(function(date) {
        var beginning = date;
        var end = ee.Date(date).advance(1, 'month');
        var mean = chirps.filterDate(beginning, end)
                    .mean()
                    .set('date', date);
        
        var month = ee.Date(date).getRelative('month', 'year').add(1);
        return mean.subtract(
            means.filter(ee.Filter.eq('month', month)).first())
            .set('date', date);
}));
print(byMonth);

Map.addLayer(ee.Image(byMonth.first()));

var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: byMonth, 
  region: point, 
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
  scale: 10000,
  xProperty: 'date'
});
print(chart);

Map.centerObject(point, 12)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you want but calculating the monthly mean for given time period can for example be achieved like this:

```
var month1 = chirps.filter(ee.Filter.eq('month',1))
print(month1, 'month1')

var byMonth = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
      months.map(function(monthNumber) {

        var mean = chirps.filter(ee.Filter.eq('month',monthNumber))
                    .mean()
        return mean

            .set('month', monthNumber);
}));
print(byMonth);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/58232a1b8a875ce5832e5abae1650ef2

Comment: hello, I have a doubt if this code is calculating the monthly sum and then the average of the months? or is it a mean of means?